# Issues in using spark cluster from outside LAN

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to use a spark cluster from outside the cluster itself.
The problem is that spark bind to my local machine private ip and it is able to connect to the master but then workers fail to connect to my machine (driver) because of IP problems (they see my private IP, because spark binds on my private IP).
I can see that from workers log:
"--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@PRIVATE_IP_MY_LAPTOP:34355"

any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `spark.driver.host` (search for it [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) for more info) to your *public* IP, the workers will then use that address instead of the (automatically resolved) private IP.

Comment: That might work, but is not recommended, as it would limit your cluster to using only that driver machine. Better to pass that parameter when creating the spark context - see instructions at the top of the page I referenced (using SparkConf.set or using --conf).

Comment: I tried, but my pc is not able to bind on my public IP, I get errors.
Not sure if it possible bind on public IP on linux

Comment: If this public IP is constant, you can add it to /etc/hosts file on your local machine so it's resolvable from the machine itself too

Comment: could you clarify this point?
suppose it is 9.9.9.9 what should I add and why?

Comment: You should add the line "9.9.9.9      localhost" to /etc/hosts file. That would tell any process on this machine that 9.9.9.9 directs to the machine itself, so processes would be able to listen on 9.9.9.9:<some-port>.

Comment: I did but I still get:
scala> val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("spark://xxx.227.211.162:7077").setAppName("SparkExamplesMinimal").set("spark.driver.host","xx.197.15.215").set("spark.driver.port", "19042") 
conf: org.apache.spark.SparkConf = org.apache.spark.SparkConf@3e43fb40
scala> val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
...
16/02/12 16:25:01 WARN Utils: 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 19056. Attempting port 19057.
16/02/12 16:25:01 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 19057. Attempting port 19058.
16/02/12 16:25:01 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.

Comment: Is it possible there is no way to tell Workers to try to connect to my public IP, instead of trying to private and for me to bind on 0.0.0.0 ?

Comment: Setting `spark.driver.host` would work assuming you can bind to your public IP.

In my case I run Spark Driver inside docker. I can bind ports to my docker image, but application inside docker cannot bind to my public IP.

Do you know how to tackle this 'cannot bind to public IP' issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `spark.driver.bindAddress` to `0.0.0.0` so that the driver program can listen to the global.